# Update buttom in Play market after updating cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have updated cordova (from 9 to 11), cordova-android (from 8 to 10), cordova-ios (from 5 to 6), plugins, angular (from 8 to 13), and released the update of app in Play Market and App Store. I used to release apk earlier, but now I released aab.
In Play Market (android) this is only Open button and Delete button in some android devices. But it should be Update button instead of Open button. Note: owners of these devices downloaded the app early from Play Market, NOT from installing apk. In IOS it is ok, button Update exists.
What I did wrongly?

Comment: Did you wait 24h? The roll out can take a while.

Comment: the app with new version is on Play market, but Update button is still not(