# Update butto in Play market after uploading aab instead of apk

Tags: android, cordova, apk, android-app-bundle

I have cordova app.
Earlier I published my app in apk, but yesterday I published my app in aab.
When the update was uploaded, in many android devices there is no Update button in Play Market, only Open button, but the version and date of updating were changed in the page of app in Market. If I delete app from device and install from Play market, and then update aab one more time, there is Update button. But how can I force users with old apk version to update the app if they dont have Update button?
Did anyone face with this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update buttom in Play market after updating cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751636/update-buttom-in-play-market-after-updating-cordova-app)

Comment: no, it doesn't answer